# Is it possible to get a constant voltage using piezoelectric crystal by giving mechanical stress?

Tags: piezoelectric-effect

Is it possible to get a constant voltage using piezoelectric crystal by giving mechanical stress?
If it so , can I charge a 5v battery using piezoelectric effect

Comment: I don't know of any 5V batteries. Please post a link to it.

Answer (score 3):

No.

> Piezoelectricity /piˌeɪzoʊˌilɛkˈtrɪsɪti/ is the electric charge that accumulates in certain solid materials (such as crystals, certain ceramics, and biological matter such as bone, DNA and various proteins) in response to applied mechanical stress. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity)._

Note that the result of stressing the crystal is a charge and not a current. You can use the charge but once it's gone - it's gone.

The other way of thinking of it is by reasoning with the laws of thermodynamics. You are thinking of putting a one time stress energy into the material and getting a continuous stream of energy out of it. That would be free energy and that's impossible.

Comment: But if we added a few magnets and a flywheel of some sort... Hmm :)

Comment: @Wossname - don't forget to make your own zirconia/quartz bearings too ... http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/257474/magnet-generator

Answer (score 2):

no.

But With constant sine force or acceleration within the sensitive range to get a constant sine voltage.

Power is exceptionally low but can reach high voltages.

- a high impact can ignite a flammable gas in a few us.

It would be like charging a battery with a 50k resistor in series with enough energy to crank a generator much more efficiently.